# What is the purpose of Instrument assemblies in place in VS2010?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage, instrumentation

In visual studio 2010 under the test settings < data and diagnostics tab < configuration for Code Coverage you can choose whether to instrument assemblies in place when you select which assemblies you wish to apply code coverage analysis to.

By default instrument assemblies in place is checked, however when it is checked anytime I run my unit tests I will be told there is no code coverage xml file being generated. If I choose to **not** instrument assemblies in place it works fine.

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference between the options is this:

- Instrumenting in place: the binaries are instrumented in the directory where VS built them.
- Otherwise: the binaries are instrumented in the test deployment directory after they have been copied over.  The binaries in the build directory remain untouched.

Do you have any post-build scripts that move binaries around?  Depending on project references, test deployment items, and build scripts, it could be that in the "in place" case, VS is instrumenting binaries that aren't actually being deployed when your unit tests are run.

Comment: No i don't have any type of deployment item or post build processes.